# var myFunction = function() {}; vs function myFunction() {};

Tags: javascript

What do you think, which one is the better, faster, nicer solution to declare a function?

First:

```
(var) myFunction = function(){
//Stuff to do
};
```

or Second:

```
function myFunction() {
//Stuff to do
};
```

Both will work in JavaScript and JQuery. But what do you think is better?

Comment: everyone loves some or the other coding style. I think the second one is still a better option, as its more readable and efficient

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that both behave differently - functions defined by `function` statement are defined before the code executes.

```
typeof f; //returns 'undefined'
var f = function() {};
```

but

```
typeof f; //returns 'function'
function f() {}
```

(Have you also noted where I did and where I didn't use semicolon?)

Also, function statements (the second option) are forbidden in blocks. It is not defined how the following should work:

```
if (false) {
    function f(){}
}
```

thus it's possible that function `f` will be, although illogically, declared in some browsers. However, it's permitted to do the following:

```
var f;
if (some expr) {
    f = function() {};
}
```

Next time better search before asking a question, [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)